# Write hash into 'value' in select_tag using options_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a collection that looks like:

```
CONST_COLLECTION:{
  "Attribute name 1"=>{:one_key=>"First Value", :second_key=>"Second Value"},
  "Attribute name 2"=>{:one_key=>"Value 3", :second_key=>"Value 4"},
  "Attribute name 3"=>{:one_key=>"Value 5", :second_key=>"Value 6"}
}
```

I have to show a drop-down list where options should be `'Attribute name 1'` and values should eq `{:one_key=>"First Value", :second_key=>"Second Value"}`

That's my view:

```
select_tag("user[selected_attribute]", options_for_select(CONST_COLLECTION))
```

But this code produces the following:

```
<option value="Attribute name 1" one_key="First Value" second_key="Second Value">Attribute name 1</option>
<option value="Attribute name 2" one_key="Value 3" second_key="Value 4">Attribute name 2</option>
<option value="Attribute name 3" one_key="Value 5" second_key="Value 6">Attribute name 3</option>
```

And that is what controller receives when first option is selected and form is submitted:

```
Parameters: {..., "user"=>{... "selected_attribute"=>"Attribute name 1", ...}, ...}
```

Controller receives only label of drop-down list, but this hash `{:one_key=>"First Value", :second_key=>"Second Value"}` was not passed to controller.

How should I pass values to controller to receive hash value in user['selected_attribute'] like this:

```
Parameters: {..., "user"=>{... "selected_attribute"=>{:one_key=>"First Value", :second_key=>"Second Value"}, ...}, ...}
```

Thanks!